# Pass parameters to thread in C++ CLI

Tags: .net, multithreading, visual-c++, c++-cli

I searched every topic to correctly create new thread with parameter (wstring) but nothing works. How can I solve my problem?
This project I create to my .Net UI Application, so earlier I use std::thread and std::mutex but "amazing" .NET in VSC++ Forms doesn't doesn't support it.

```
namespace indx
{
ref class FileIndex
{
public:
    FileIndex();
    FileIndex(FileIndex ^);
    virtual ~FileIndex();

    // func
    void getDrives();
    void Diving(const wstring &);
    void Processing();
};

void FileIndex::Diving(Object^ data)
{
    // do smth.
    // any recursion 
}

void FileIndex::Processing()
{
    vector<DriveInfo>::iterator ittr = LDrivers->begin();
    for(counter = 0; ittr != LDrivers->end(); ittr++)
    {
        if(ittr->type == L"Fixed" || ittr->type == L"Removable")
        {
            // need new thread(&FileIndex::Diving, this, (ittr->drive + L"*"));
            // argument - ittr->drive + L"*";
        }
    }
    // join
}
```

Comment: std::wstring is not a .NET class and does not derive from System::Object.  There is no point in using it, use a String^ instead.  That vector<> code doesn't look healthy either.

Comment: I have very huge list of funtions that indexing drives and std::wstring with WinApi functions using everywere, so I I can't alter it. It is wery important part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your code fragment it is not so easy to point in the right direction. You need a thread object.

```
using namespace System::Threading;
```

The thread object:

```
Thread ^m_Thread;
```

and the needed line is now:

```
m_Thread = gcnew Thread(gcnew ParameterizedThreadStart(this,
                    &FileIndex::Diving));
m_Thread->Start(ittr->drive + L"*");
```

As Hans Passant suggest in his comment. The Start method will not accept a native c++ value like I think `DriverInfo` is. You have to convert it to a real C++/CLI object. 
And again Hans Passant point into the right direction:

```
ref class mywrapwstring
{
 public:
  mywrapwstring(std::wstring str) :  str(new std::wstring(str)) {}
  !mywrapwstring() :  { delete std::string(str); }
  std::wstring *str;
};
```

and the "magic" call:

```
m_Thread->Start(gcnew mywrapwstring(ittr->drive + L"*") );
```

and the thread method better like:

```
void FileIndex::Diving(mywrapwstring ^ data)
{
 // do smth.
 // any recursion 
 data->str; // here is your string
}
```

Comment: DriveInfo it is a structure with some wstring and size_t variables. What is a native C++/CLI object that replace "struct"?

Comment: @ArsenBoykanych you can pass the whole structure in the wrapping class instead of the std::wstring or event together as second attribut. I would prefer that anyway.

Comment: It must be a wstring* and you must implement the finalizer to destroy it.

Comment: ref class mywrapwstring
{
 public:
  mywrapwstring(std::wstring str) : str(str) {}
  std::wstring str;
};

wstring doesn't support managed class type.

Comment: @HansPassant honestly it is over 2 years ago I build my last C++/CLI program. You are right of course.