# How to pass an object to a thread in C++ CLI WinForms?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms, object, pass-by-reference

I am working on windows forms c++ project,

I am able to laodlibrary my.dll and get returned Object from dll then the call dll methods inside a button_click (winform.h)

I need to use the same Object and call a DLL method in a thread how to do this? my current code as follows

Imy.h is an interface class object, this interface is derived by dll class

```
public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

public:
  void mythread(Imy &pImy) {//the returned object in button_click object should be pass to here
    //and call  pImy->callmyfunc2("test");
}


private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    typedef Imy* (*PFN_Factory)();
    
    HINSTANCE hDLL = LoadLibrary(L"my.dll"); // Handle to DLL
    Imy* pImy = NULL;
    PFN_Factory functionPtr;
    
    functionPtr = reinterpret_cast<PFN_Factory>(GetProcAddress(hDLL, "CreateObject")); // Get the function pointer
    pImy = functionPtr(); // Get pointer to object

    pImy ->callmyfunc1(); // call method 1st from the returned object

    //pImy ->callmyfunc2("test"); // this should be run in a thread  
    
    ThreadStart^ ThreadMethod1 = gcnew ThreadStart(pImy , &MyForm::mythread); // does not work i want to know how to this
    Thread^ MyThread1 = gcnew Thread(ThreadMethod1);
    MyThread1->Start();
}
```

Comment: The simple way is to LoadLibrary in the worker thread.  If not suitable then you must declare the method correctly, it needs an Object^ parameter.  Write a little helper class to store and pass the pointer.  safe_cast<> to cast the Object^

Comment: @Hans Passant can you explain in code how to perform this? **it needs an Object^ parameter. Write a little helper class to store and pass the pointer. safe_cast<> to cast the Object^**

Comment: does this helps you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708985/pass-parameters-to-thread-in-c-cli